# Codeignite hello world code in docs doent work

Tags: php, codeigniter

I just started using CodeIgniter and I'm stuck at the hello world code in the docs. Each time I type in the name of the blog controller in the url bar and hit enter, I get this error:
[404 Error Page Not Found!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4yBKB.jpg)

**localhost/php/CodeIgniter/.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

**route.php**

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

**config.php**

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/php/CodeIgniter/';
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

**controllers/Blog.php**

```
<?php
    class Blog extends CI_Controller {

            public function index()
            {
                    echo 'Hello World!';
            }
    }
```

**How Can I Resolve This?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set a URL string on [route.php] corresponding controller class/method.

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'blog/index';
$route['blog/(:any)'] = 'blog/show/$1'
```

You can leave the URL "http://localhost/" referencing "/" as home by default_controller on route.php

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost';
```

Please browse more about .htaccess and friendly URL. If you get 404 error maybe your URL is not friendly.

Friendly:

```
http://localhost/blog/lorem-ipsum
```

Not Friendly:

```
http://localhost/index.php/blog/lorem-ipsum
```

Documentation: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html